# in catalog module i found method called addShortcut but in that method there is an use of instanceof i did not understand what it is

Tags: magento2, blocks

```
public function addShortcut(Template $block)
{
    if ($block instanceof ShortcutInterface) {
        $this->_shortcuts[] = $block;
    }
}
```

here is the function which im talking about , in if block there is an use of instanceof method may i know what exactly happening in if block and what is the use of instanceof in it.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` is used to [determine whether a PHP variable is an instantiated object of a certain class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)

In this case, a pseudo code translation of this method would be:

```
if the block is of the ShortcutInterface class/interface 
    add the $block variable to the _shortcuts array
```

The `addShortcut` method is used with the Paypal module in Magento.

To add a shortcut you need a code that looks like this:

```
$shortcut = $shortcutButtons->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor/module_block_name');

$shortcutButtons->addShortcut($shortcut);
```

Where `$shortcutButtons` is a container and the block corresponding to `vendor/module_block_name` must implement the `ShortcutInterface`

Example:

```
class Button extends Template implements ShortcutInterface
```